# Where's the proper place to disconnect a MutationObserver after it observes added nodes?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I need a MutationObserver to observe an added node, stop observing that node, and then reconnect to observe additional added nodes.  This works fine without the observer.disconnect();

```
    var startNode = document.body,
        config = { childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: false, characterData: false },
        observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);

    function mutationCallback(mutations) {
       mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
             doThings(node);
          });
       });
    }

    function doThings(node) {
       console.log(node.nodeType);
       startNode = node;
       observer.disconnect();
       observer.observe(startNode,config);
    }

    doThings(startNode);
```

However, I'd like to be able to disconnect if possible.  Where should the disconnect live and is it necessary to do so?

Comment: Why go to all that trouble? You'll get notifications just observing on `document.body` anyway, as you're monitoring the subtree.

Comment: This is true and originally how I had it.  I will probably just revert.  Thanks.